# Is it possible for a plugin to force reading and writing of uploaded images to a database instead of to a filesystem?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, core, uploads

I am trying to configure a WordPress site using a server cluster and independent file systems. The problem is keeping the wp_content/uploads folder synchronized across all the server instances. My preferred solution is to "write" and "read" these files to/from a shared database.

So my basic question is whether this is possible to code in a plugin, or would require WordPress core modifications (which I'd rather avoid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should have quite reasonable options to customize upload, there are plenty of existing solutions around.

As for specifics I am not sure on "database" as image storage option. They typical solutions that I've heard of are:

- dedicated location behind CDN (or some variation of);
- dedicated image storage service, such as Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this is reasonable, and pointing out s3. I've found a few plug-ins (https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/tcs3/) that I can use as a starting point for my development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an interesting option. But what do you mean when you say database, for sure not MySQL database, and I will remove this from any consideration.

MySQL should not grow in size, and should be easy for import export this is why.

Considering that currently, WordPress can work on MySQL and MariaDB mostly I would say you are asking about S3 and CDN like databases, like CloudFlare, that can do that automatic for you btw.

OK, I posted this just to say you may consider GitHub as your CDN.

Comment: You seem to have very strong opinions about MySQL.

Comment: GitHub is explicitly not a CDN and should not be used as such both technically and by terms of service. There are specialized CDNs that proxy assets hosted on GitHub exactly for that reason.

Comment: I don't know about TOS, all I know you can host your website for free on GitHub. If your website also has images I don't see how is this wrong @Rarst.

Comment: @MikeGodin, I saw 3-10TB databases, however storing the binary images in MySQL doesn't sound as a smart choice, I guess you haven't thought of SVG images.

Comment: Even Pages feature has bandwidth limits and that's different from just dumping assets of third party site there.

Comment: @Rarst, I am sure this is so. However, I know many websites that just work on GitHub. But yes, limits are everywhere.